# SQL index searching

Tags: sql, indexing, database

For the this task I'm supposed to find all the names of actors who have participated in more than 50 movies. For every movie I've got to check that their lastname is coming first in the alphabeth with the other actors in the movie.

```
select 
     lastname, firstname, count(*) as films
from 
     (select 
           distinct p.lastname, p.firstname, f.filmid
      from 
           person p, filmparticipation f, filmitem i, film fi
      where 
           fi.filmid = i.filmid and
           i.filmid = f.filmid and
           p.personid = f.personid and
           f.parttype = 'cast' and filmtype = 'C') person
 group by 
     lastname, firstname
 having 
     count(*) >= 450
 order by 
     lastname, firstname desc;
```

Here are some relevant tables regarding the query

```
create table person(
personid int primary key,
lastname text not null,
firstname text not null,
gender(1),
);
create index personlastnameindex on person (lastname);

create table filmparticipation (
partid int primary key,
personid int not null references person (personid),
filmid int not null references filmitem (filmid),
parttype text not null
);

create index filmparticipationpersonidindex on filmparticipation (personid);
create index filmparticipationpersonidindex on filmparticipation (filmid);

create table film(
filmid int primary key references filmitem (filmid),
title text not null,
prodyear int
);

create index filmtitleindex on film (title);
create index filmyearindex on film (prodyear);
```

Some explainasions regarding some filmtypes =>

```
 C => cinema movie V => videomovie VG => videogame TV => TV-film.....
```

How do I actually make it check that the person is coming up first in the alphabeth vs the other actors?

Example => Movie pulp fiction... (there are several other actors but taking the main chars)
Samuel L. Jackson || John Travolta        Easy thing to see that Jackson is coming before Travolta, so +1 in count for Jackson etc...

I've seen a pseudo code that looks like min(p.lastname in that movie) or p.lastname <= all(p.lastname in a movie)

How can I use either of them? Or is it a better way?

Comment: What's with the `filmitem` table? Can't see the creation of that table.

Comment: So you only want to count the actors that are first in the list (when the actor list of an movie is ordered by their last name)?

Comment: A movie has a casting list. Given that casting list for that movie, im supossed to get min(p.lastname) from that list and count it somehow

Comment: @CptHindsight: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL etc) are you using?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL. Was Oracle before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using an RDBMS that includes row_number() over, try:

```
select lastname, 
       firstname, 
       count(distinct filmid) as films,
       count(distinct case when rn=1 then filmid end) as alpha_first
from 
(select p.lastname,
        p.firstname,
        f.filmid,
        row_number() over (partition by f.filmid order by lastname, firstname) rn
 from person p, filmparticipation f, filmitem i, film fi
 where fi.filmid = i.filmid and
       i.filmid = f.filmid and
       p.personid = f.personid and
       f.parttype = 'cast' and filmtype = 'C') person
group by lastname, firstname
having count(distinct filmid) >= 50
order by lastname, firstname desc;
```